# How to get a list of arrays in tcl

Tags: arraylist, tcl

I did some research but only find [ugly hacks](http://pinds.com/2000/09/18/datastructures-in-tcl/), which uses unique name for each array element and save the names into a list. Is there any way to do this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of arrays, you want to use dictionaries:  http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/dict.htm

Dictionaries are first-class variables and can be passed around (and placed in a list) just like other variables.

```
% set d1 [dict create a b c d]
% set d2 [dict create e f g h i j]
% set lst [list $d1 $d2]
% set lst  ;# ==> {a b c d} {e f g h i j}
```

Comment: Also, `array get` returns a dictionary in 8.5

Answer (score 2):

At work, we still use Tcl 8.4. I know that dict has been back-ported, but it is not part of the standard packages. For 8.4, we use keyed list from the Tclx package. here is an example:

```
# Problem: I want to create a list of arrays
# Solution: For 8.5, I can have list of dict, but for 8.4, use 
# keyedlist in place of dict. This script is written for 8.4

package require Tclx

# Create individual users and a list
keylset user1 id 101 alias john; # {{id 101} {alias john}}
keylset user2 id 102 alias ally; # {{id 102} {alias ally}}
set users [list $user1 $user2]

# Show the list
foreach user $users {
    puts "ID:    [keylget user id]"
    puts "Alias: [keylget user alias]"
    puts ""
}
```

Output:

```
ID:    101
Alias: john

ID:    102
Alias: ally
```